# Golang linux RSS shows more bytes than pprof runtime.MemStats

Tags: go, memory

I have a socket client Golang program. when it just start up, Linux /proc/PID/status show the process RSS is 15204 kB, but the pprof report shows that HeapAlloc is about 1408 kB, there is a gap of about 14000kB.
My Questions:

1、Why is there such a big difference?

2、How is the go application memory distributed? Besides heap and stack, are there other memory areas? and how can I find these areas?

3、More importantly, how can I lower its rss?

cat /proc/PID/status:

```
Umask:  0000
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   3393
Ngid:   0
Pid:    3393
PPid:   2882
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    500     500     500     500
Gid:    500     500     500     500
FDSize: 32
Groups: 500 
NStgid: 3393
NSpid:  3393
NSpgid: 2881
NSsid:  2881
VmPeak:   806492 kB
VmSize:   806492 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     15204 kB
VmRSS:     15204 kB
RssAnon:            5024 kB
RssFile:           10180 kB
RssShmem:              0 kB
VmData:    10988 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:      5164 kB
VmLib:         8 kB
VmPTE:        28 kB
VmPMD:         0 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        6
SigQ:   0/937
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000001
SigCgt: fffffffe7fc1fefe
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Cpus_allowed:   3
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-1
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        261951
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     21327
```

go tool pprof heap:

```
# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 1408048
# TotalAlloc = 45071968
# Sys = 10828924
# Lookups = 0
# Mallocs = 889174
# Frees = 885421
# HeapAlloc = 1408048
# HeapSys = 7929856
# HeapIdle = 5677056
# HeapInuse = 2252800
# HeapReleased = 5480448
# HeapObjects = 3753
# Stack = 458752 / 458752
# MSpan = 25120 / 32768
# MCache = 1736 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 725549
# GCSys = 886912
# OtherSys = 778703
# NextGC = 4194304
# LastGC = 1645757614280889245
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "Why is there such a big difference?"

These are two different metrics. What people call "memory consumption" is
incredibly hard to even *define* on modern machines.

2. "How is the go application memory distributed?"

This is an implementation detail and varies. Nothing actuable to know here.

"Besides heap and stack, are there other memory areas?"

No, but note that the heap/stack dichotomy is an implementation detail of a certain (albeit common) compiler/compiler version/system combination.

"and how can I find these areas?" You cannot.

3. "More importantly, how can I lower its rss?"

By reducing how much memory you allocate. But note that lowering RSS most probably simply isn't needed. You probably overestimate how "problematic" a "large" RSS is.

Comment: Thanks for relpy. My scenario is on an embedded machine with limited memory resources, I have to reduce the memory usage of this golang app, otherwise it won't run. Do we have any other way?

Comment: @Wang If you have to reduce the memory consumption you will have to _do_ it. Use data structures with less memory footprint, use algorithms with less memory footprint, use algorithms that can work on streams, reduce allocations, reuse allocated memory, tune GOGC. There is no magical "half-rss-usage" flag.